# scheduling jobs in linux by python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

OS What I'm using: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

I'm scheduling some jobs running python script to print "hello" every minute today 10:00, but not execute.

I checked python3 path, and file path:

```
$ locate schedule_jobs.py
/home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py
$ which python3
/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3
```

The python script `schedule_jobs.py`:

```
import time
import os 
import subprocess

# a = subprocess.check_output(['ls'])

print("hello 030")
```

The command command I ran:

```
* 10 24 10 * /home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py
```

Crontab screenshot:

[image: linux corntab picture]

**wondering how come it not work for me**

---

the purpose I expect , usually in factory have lot of Raspberry Pi, record temperature, product amount etc, I practicing/end goal of one computer with correct python script (linux system run schedule jobs) can gather all data every hour from numbers of Raspberry Pi . I want to make my question simple so if I can solve schedule print, then the rest rest shouldn't be a problem, thanks

---

**problem shooting:**

> From the cron man page:
>
> > When executing commands, any output is mailed to the owner of the
> > crontab (or to the user named in the MAILTO environment variable in
> > the crontab, if such exists). The children copies of cron running
> > these processes have their name coerced to uppercase, as will be seen
> > in the syslog and ps output.
>
> So should check your/root's mail, or the syslog (eg. /var/log/syslog).

I checked my `mail` and `ls` mail

here is the output:

```
(base) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:~$ crontab -l
# my crontab print:
* 10 26 10 * /home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py

(base) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:~$ mail
Cannot open mailbox /var/mail/joy: no such file or dir
No mail for joy
(base) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:~$ cd /var/mail
(base) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:/var/mail$ ls
```

I list inside `/var/log`

```
(base) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:/var/log$ ls
alternatives.log    boot.log.2     dpkg.log.1              private
alternatives.log.1  boot.log.3     faillog                 speech-dispatcher
apport.log          boot.log.4     fontconfig.log          syslog
apport.log.1        boot.log.5     gdm3                    syslog.1
apport.log.2.gz     boot.log.6     gpu-manager.log         syslog.2.gz
apport.log.3.gz     boot.log.7     gpu-manager-switch.log  syslog.3.gz
apport.log.4.gz     bootstrap.log  hp                      syslog.4.gz
apport.log.5.gz     btmp           installer               ubuntu-advantage.log
apport.log.6.gz     btmp.1         journal                 ubuntu-advantage-timer.log
apport.log.7.gz     cups           kern.log                ubuntu-advantage-timer.log.1
apt                 dist-upgrade   kern.log.1              unattended-upgrades
auth.log            dmesg          kern.log.2.gz           wtmp
auth.log.1          dmesg.0        kern.log.3.gz           Xorg.0.log
auth.log.2.gz       dmesg.1.gz     kern.log.4.gz           Xorg.0.log.old
auth.log.3.gz       dmesg.2.gz     lastlog                 Xorg.1.log
auth.log.4.gz       dmesg.3.gz     mail.err
boot.log            dmesg.4.gz     mail.log
boot.log.1          dpkg.log       openvpn
(base) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:/var/log$ cd /var/log/syslog
bash: cd: /var/log/syslog: no such file or dir
```

`cat/read` inside `syslog`

```
(base) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:/var/log$ cat syslog
Oct 26 10:17:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8370]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 26 10:18:11 joy-System-Product-Name crontab[8410]: (joy) LIST (joy)
Oct 26 10:18:31 joy-System-Product-Name crontab[8414]: (joy) BEGIN EDIT (joy)
Oct 26 10:18:43 joy-System-Product-Name gnome-shell[1457]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x55650482e2f0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Oct 26 10:18:43 joy-System-Product-Name gnome-shell[1457]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x556506dc7ae0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Oct 26 10:18:43 joy-System-Product-Name gnome-shell[1457]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x5565064e46c0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Oct 26 10:21:29 joy-System-Product-Name crontab[8414]: (joy) REPLACE (joy)
Oct 26 10:21:29 joy-System-Product-Name crontab[8414]: (joy) END EDIT (joy)
Oct 26 10:21:35 joy-System-Product-Name crontab[8446]: (joy) BEGIN EDIT (joy)
Oct 26 10:21:38 joy-System-Product-Name crontab[8446]: (joy) END EDIT (joy)
Oct 26 10:21:41 joy-System-Product-Name crontab[8451]: (joy) LIST (joy)
Oct 26 10:22:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[895]: (joy) RELOAD (crontabs/joy)
Oct 26 10:22:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8459]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:22:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8461]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:22:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8461]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:22:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8458]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:23:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8482]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:23:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8484]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:23:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8484]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:23:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8481]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:24:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8500]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:24:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8502]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:24:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8502]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:24:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8499]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:24:07 joy-System-Product-Name dbus-daemon[1189]: [session uid=1000 pid=1189] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.41' (uid=1000 pid=1457 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Oct 26 10:24:07 joy-System-Product-Name dbus-daemon[1189]: [session uid=1000 pid=1189] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Oct 26 10:24:07 joy-System-Product-Name dbus-daemon[896]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.114' (uid=1000 pid=8506 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
Oct 26 10:24:07 joy-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Oct 26 10:24:07 joy-System-Product-Name dbus-daemon[896]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Oct 26 10:24:07 joy-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Oct 26 10:24:07 joy-System-Product-Name gnome-shell[1457]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x55650482e2f0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Oct 26 10:24:07 joy-System-Product-Name gnome-shell[1457]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x556509502b10] is on because it needs an allocation.
Oct 26 10:24:07 joy-System-Product-Name gnome-shell[1457]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x5565064e5140] is on because it needs an allocation.
Oct 26 10:24:07 joy-System-Product-Name nautilus[8506]: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 無法執行副程序「net」(No such file or directory)
Oct 26 10:24:25 joy-System-Product-Name gvfsd[8550]: got no contact to IPC$
Oct 26 10:24:37 joy-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 26 10:25:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8582]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:25:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8584]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:25:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8584]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:25:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8581]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:26:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8588]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:26:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8590]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:26:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8590]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:26:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8587]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:27:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8599]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:27:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8601]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:27:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8601]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:27:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8598]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:28:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8605]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:28:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8607]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:28:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8607]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:28:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8604]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:29:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8636]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:29:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8638]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:29:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8638]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:29:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8635]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:30:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8653]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
Oct 26 10:30:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8654]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:30:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8656]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:30:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8656]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:30:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8652]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:31:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8666]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:31:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8668]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:31:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8668]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:31:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8665]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:31:55 joy-System-Product-Name google-chrome.desktop[6739]: [1026/103155.026665:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(152)] open /home/joy/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports/pending/00d7c804-f745-4483-b2f4-917e7ba74262.lock: File exists (17)
Oct 26 10:32:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8693]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:32:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8695]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:32:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8695]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:32:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8692]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:33:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8706]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:33:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8708]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:33:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8708]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:33:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8705]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:34:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8722]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:34:01 joy-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Oct 26 10:34:01 joy-System-Product-Name anacron[8723]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2022-10-26
Oct 26 10:34:01 joy-System-Product-Name anacron[8723]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Oct 26 10:34:01 joy-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: anacron.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 26 10:34:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8725]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:34:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8725]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:34:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8721]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:35:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8741]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:35:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8743]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:35:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8743]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:35:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8740]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:35:05 joy-System-Product-Name google-chrome.desktop[6739]: Error in cpuinfo: failed to parse processor information from /proc/cpuinfo
Oct 26 10:36:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8776]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:36:02 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8778]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:36:02 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8778]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:36:02 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8775]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:37:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8790]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:37:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8792]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:37:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8792]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:37:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8789]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:38:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8826]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:38:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8828]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:38:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8828]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:38:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8825]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:39:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8850]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:39:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8852]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:39:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8852]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:39:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8849]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:40:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8860]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:40:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8862]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:40:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8862]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:40:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8859]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:41:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8865]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:41:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8867]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:41:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8867]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:41:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8864]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:42:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8872]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:42:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8874]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:42:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8874]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:42:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8871]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:43:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8880]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:43:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8882]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:43:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8882]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:43:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8879]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:44:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8889]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:44:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8891]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:44:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8891]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:44:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8888]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:45:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8903]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:45:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8905]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:45:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8905]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:45:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8902]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
Oct 26 10:45:31 joy-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: fwupd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 26 10:45:31 joy-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: fwupd.service: Consumed 1.084s CPU time.
Oct 26 10:46:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8930]: (joy) CMD (/home/joy/miniconda3/bin/python3 /home/joy/fe_dir/schedule_jobs.py)
Oct 26 10:46:01 joy-System-Product-Name cron[8932]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:46:01 joy-System-Product-Name postfix/sendmail[8932]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Oct 26 10:46:01 joy-System-Product-Name CRON[8929]: (joy) MAIL (mailed 10 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
```

problem conclusion:

1. Crontab execute script `schedule_jobs.py`
2. but not seen "hello 030" in cmd output or email
3. no sure `syslog` record step 1 or not

---

here is what I get so far, any suggestion, thanks

Comment: Firstly, 10 is 10 AM. 10 PM would be 22 (it's probably not that but... you know... just double checking). Secondly, the output of crontab jobs doesn't go to a terminal, but to (usually) an email address. Check [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40624/16046). Maybe is that?

Comment: @BorrajaX Wow, I didn't know about the cron email thing. I believe you inadvertently solved the mystery of why my hard drive is so full.